# codeigniter function run without being called, weird

Tags: codeigniter

I have a library called Traffic, I use it when I need to record user visit. I autoload it in the autoload config file, but only call the method function when needed.

```
class Traffic {

    function monitor()
    {
        $CI=& get_instance();

        $ip = $CI->input->ip_address();

        $input = array( 'ip' => $ip);
        $CI->db->insert('traffic', $input);
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
class Post extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->traffic->monitor();
        $this->load->view('post_view');
    }

}
```

This is post_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://sample.com/photo/img_2133.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, if the image in the page can not be found (it was deleted), the insertion will have happen twice. Look like the 404 error method monitor() of the traffic class. Even though I did not ask it to do so.

So if the post view page has 10 images, and all of them was deleted or not exist, my traffic table will have 11 new records. 1 for what I called in the controller, and 10 for 404 error.

How can I stop 404 error automatically call the monitor method. And how the hell did the 404 errors have access to my library?

UPDATE:

my htaccess

```
#this code redirect site to non www address then remove index.php from url
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';

$route['(login|post)'] = "$1";
$route['(login|post)/(:any)'] = "$1/$2";
$route['(:any)'] = "post/index/$1";
```

Comment: It would be useful to understand what you mean by saying "an image in the page..." What page? Show us. What do you mean by "app"? Show us.

Comment: Is that library or controller code?

Comment: @DFriend hey I update the question

Comment: Thanks for including some code. In class Traffic, the call to ` $CI->db->insert('traffic', $input);` implies a model has been loaded. How/where?

Comment: `href` is not a valid attribute for an <img> element. DId you mean `<img src="http://... />`?

Comment: @DFriend yes it was src attribute, sorry my misspelling

Comment: @DFriend I did not use model, just active record and controller

Comment: Where and how do you load the database?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Used your code, made a simple 'traffic' table, put non-existent image as `src` in the view and directed browser to `http://myhost/post` Works for me. Single entry in table. Missing image place-holder on view. No 404 issues. I am using Codeigniter v3.0.3 though which could be the difference.  Any other code in this process you are not sharing?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2. I'll reproduce in a clean install and paste it here.

Comment: Seems that you have an error within your routes or even with url-rewriting in .htaccess file. Could you show us them?

Comment: @f_martinez: updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within the routing. Let's see to the example of image URL `photos/image.jpg`.

First, according to the rules in *.htaccess* the URL (it doesn't match an existing file) is changed to `index.php/photos/image.jpg`.

Second, according to the rule `(:any)` the URL is changed to `post/index/photos/image.jpg`, which refers to the *index* method of *Post* controller. So every deleted image causes insertion to the `traffic` table.

The solution is to filter requests within *photos* directory and make server to throw genuine 404 HTTP-errors for discontinued images. For example, you can do that by adding *photos* directory to the *.htaccess* rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|photos|robots\.txt)
```